# Loading Dating without a separate TRAIN/TEST Directory : Pytorch (ImageFolder)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

My data is not distributed in train and test directories but only in classes. I mean:

```
image-folders/
   ├── class_0/
   |   ├── 001.jpg
   |   ├── 002.jpg
   └── class_1/
   |   ├── 001.jpg
   |   └── 002.jpg
   └── class_2/
       ├── 001.jpg
       └── 002.jpg
```

Is it the right way to approach the problem (What this does is: take datafolder and than divide it into **train**, **valid** and **test** sets. However, i am worried if it is the samething as valid/dev set even though "test set" will not go through training and validation loop):

```
        data = datasets.ImageFolder('PATH', transform)
        # creating a train / valid split
# valid set will be further divided into valid and test sets
indices = list(range(len(data)))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
split = int(np.floor(valid_size * len(data)))
train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]

# Creating a valid and test set
valid_idx = valid_idx[int(np.floor(0.2*len(valid_idx))) : len(valid_idx)]
test_idx = valid_idx[0:int(np.floor (0.2 * len(valid_idx) ) )]

# define samplers for obtaining training and validation batches
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_idx)    
    # prepare data loaders (combine dataset and sampler)
        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler, num_workers=num_workers)
        valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler, num_workers=num_workers)
        test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=test_sampler  num_workers=num_workers)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question about train/valid/test sets vs train/valid sets?

Comment: I know the difference between train/valid vs. train/valid/test/sets.. My question is rather about loading data with pytorch. Loading data with pytorch when it is not splitted in train and test directories.......
Furthermore, Is it ok to to split the data the way i did in above given code. splitting train, valid and test set from the same ImageFolder (pytorch requires to create different for train and test)

Answer (score 3):

This seems ok to me. Alternatively you can create three separate datasets from `data`, using [`torch.utils.data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split). This has the benefit of not having to worry about implementing the samplers for your dataloaders:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split

dl_args = dict(batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=num_workers)
```

- With a **train/validation** split:

  ```
  >>> data = datasets.ImageFolder('PATH', transform)
  >>> n_val = int(np.floor(valid_size * len(data)))
  >>> n_train = len(data) - n_val
  ```

  Datasets and dataloaders initialization:

  ```
  >>> train_ds, val_ds = random_split(data, [n_train, n_val])

  >>> train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, **dl_args)
  >>> valid_dl = DataLoader(val_ds , **dl_args)
  ```
- With a **train/validation/test** split:

  ```
  >>> data = datasets.ImageFolder('PATH', transform)
  >>> n_val = int(np.floor(valid_size * len(data)))
  >>> n_test = int(np.floor(test_size * len(data)))
  >>> n_train = len(data) - n_val - n_test
  ```

  Datasets and dataloaders initialization:

  ```
  >>> train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = random_split(data, [n_train, n_val, n_test])

  >>> train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, **dl_args)
  >>> valid_dl = DataLoader(val_ds, **dl_args)
  >>> test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds, **dl_args)
  ```